# Undo edits just suggested

Tags: support, editing, suggested-edits

Is there a way to undo an edit that one has suggested before it has been reviewed? I realized that my edit on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/185061/26188) was wrong.

Comment: Related feature request on meta.SE: [How can I cancel an edit I made on another user's question or answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80933/how-can-i-cancel-an-edit-i-made-on-another-users-question-or-answer). (This issue has been brought up again on this meta: [Can we reject our own edit?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/24914/can-we-reject-our-own-edit))

Comment: A recent question about the same issue: [Is it possible to take back my suggestion on edit an answer or (question)?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32939)

Comment: Still a nowadays problem. Could  you include the `featute-request` tag?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, this is currently not possible. As a workaround you can consider to leave a comment on the post, indicating that your edit should not be approved. This could help the reviewers to make the correct decisions, or if ever it still gets approved, help somebody clean up the issue.

If you think the feature you ask about would be useful and you want to see it implemented, you can vote for [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)s on meta.SE:

- [How can I cancel an edit I made on another user's question or answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80933/how-can-i-cancel-an-edit-i-made-on-another-users-question-or-answer)
- [Why can't I cancel an edit action?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123355/why-cant-i-cancel-an-edit-action)

Comment: I have posted this answer mainly because the same question appears repeatedly on this site (as you can see from the [linked questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/4969)). Although there are some comments with pointers to meta.SE, no answers had been posted so far. If none of these posts has answer, none of them can be closed as a duplicate.