# Is it possible to take back my suggestion on edit an answer or (question)?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I recently suggested an edit to an answer on MSE site, but a few minute later I realized I was wrong and the answer didn't need that edit. So I clicked on the edit again to find an option to cancel edit suggestion but I couldn't find that. Therefore I make the changes back to what was the original answer!

My question: Is there any way to cancel the suggested edit that sent? If not, do you agree with me that it is a good idea to provide that option on MSE?

Comment: When did you realize you were wrong?  Did you not read the question carefully?  Did you assume the asker meant something other than what they wrote or meant?  Good edit suggestions are for more valuable that *quick* edit suggestions.

Comment: @amWhy In fact I've been edited an answer to my question. Just a minute after editing I realized I was wrong.

Comment: I agree sometimes we decide too fast.

Comment: The good news (or bad news if you edit too fast) is, at 2k reps your edits won't need to be reviewed: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit For me, this was probably the most relieving privilege, after commenting at 50 reps: I don't like to leave mistakes, especially in names, and they are too small edits to be accepted in review queue.

Comment: See also: [Undo edits just suggested](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4969).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut it is even more scary! I think it would be better to provide this privilege for users who have at least 10k reps .

Comment: @Etemon Do you know how to rollback to a previous revision?

Comment: @TymaGaidash Yes but now I have more than 2k reps and I can roll back to previous revision. But if I remember correctly when I had less than 2k reps I suggested an edit and only the person who accepted it could rollback.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not possible: [How can I cancel an edit I made on another user's question or answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80933/295232)

What I usually do is change the edit summary to include something like 'PLEASE REJECT', to help the reviewers. Having a single rejected suggested edit doesn't penalize you in any way; you need at least [5 rejections in 7 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92337/295232) to suffer a ban.

Comment: Also, the OP's question, like your hack when you realize a suggested edit was problematic, reveal we all need to think twice about being to eager to suggest edits.